# How to form a SQL query for a one to many relation?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, one-to-many, yii

I have two MySQL tables: `house` and `features`. This is for a real estate website.

`house` has this structure:

```
id | address | ... some other fields
```

`features` has this structure:

```
id | house_id | feature | value
```

as you can guess, a house can have multiple features, so a 1:n relationship exists.

Now, I'm implementing a search form for houses. I need to filter the results based on the features selected by the user.

Sample scenario: get all houses which have the features `garage` and `garden`, and a list of features in those houses.

What would be the best query to suit my needs? I'm not familiar with JOIN operations, so I need your help!

(OPTIONAL) If you can provide a Yii Framework-specific solution, it would be awesome :)

Comment: I know :( I should hang out in SO more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM HOUSE H JOIN FEATURES F ON H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_ID
WHERE FEATURE IN ('GARDEN','GARAGE');
```

Comment: OK, What should I do if I want houses with BOTH garden AND garage? Your query provides houses with EITHER garden OR garage. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to join it manually if you are using Yii.

It's easier if you use MySQL (over SQLite) and if you use InnoDB tables (over MyISAM tables).

You need to create a foreign key from Features (house_id column) to Houses (house_id column)

If you build your model using Gii, then it will create the "relation" function for you automatically.

Then in Yii, you would call House->features to get an array of feature rows.

You can pass a CDbCriteria object in the Fill() call to filter the houses that the user selected.

Comment: I'm familiar with that, but I'm looking for only the specific rows from the House table, like I've specified in the question. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: then you should change the title.

Comment: also, your db design is not normal. you can have a variety of similar feature names like "rooms", "roms", "rooms", "roomz". this is not a great design. just use columns like they were intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you need **only** the columns from the **House table**:

SELECT * from HOUSE where ID in (SELECT ID from FEATURES where FEATURE IN('GARDEN','GARAGE'));

If you need the entire details:

SELECT * 
FROM HOUSE H JOIN FEATURES F ON H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_ID
WHERE FEATURE IN ('GARDEN','GARAGE');